# Easy-PHP's apache stops listening on IP after network reset

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, lan, easyphp

I have Easy-PHP running on a Windows PC connected to two local networks on ranges `192.168.10.xxx` and `192.168.20.xxx` by cable:

```
Listen 192.168.10.57
Listen 192.168.20.70
```

At around the same time every day the `192.168.10.xxx` network seems to restart/reset something and the computers connected on the `192.168.10.xxx` network can't access the webpage anymore unless I restart Easy-PHP, the `192.168.20.xxx` network can still access the website.

I have no idea what's happening since a Google search for an Apache server unbinding IPs doesn't return any results and I'm not very network-savy.

So my questions are:

1. Why does that network stop being able to access the Apache server unless I restart Easy-PHP?
2. What can I do to fix it? Is there any way to make Apache check if the IP is still bound or accepting connections each X minutes?

P.S.: Tomorrow I'm going to try `Listen 80` instead of the individual IPs to see if that works.

Comment: Answering with an auto script to restart PHP isn't a good idea. You should investigate what's going on with the network equipment, as you said yourself something is resetting in the network equipment. Post more information in your question...

Comment: Sorry but I don't manage the network at all, I just run a website on the intranet. Today there were no issues after using "Listen 80" on the apache conf file, I actually found one answer on google that advised to do the same